# (Windows Git-bash) IntelliJ git bash shell color scheme messed up with Docker

Tags: windows, intellij-idea, docker, phpstorm, git-bash

(Windows Git-bash) When I use git bash for terminal in a project for IntelliJ I have problems when I log into a docker container and use `ls`. Text gets highlighted light blue and the color doesn't go away until I exit.

Any thought on how to correct this? I suspect this comes from IntelliJ's recoloring of the shell colors. Perhaps there is a way to remove the influence of the Darkula theme colors?

[image]

Here is what the same looks like on a normal OS panel:

[image]

Comment: If you think it's Darcula then ... `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Colros & Fonts | Console Colors`. But since it's a Terminal .. IDE takes your OS colors (from your OS shell preferences) -- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205435490/comments/204857770

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you for the link, I have updated with an example OS window, the problem doesn't exist there.

Comment: Well .. the best I can suggest is to change the color schema used in your OS terminal (to be more traditional -- white on black) and see how it will look (note that IDE restart might be required .. as I do not know at what point IDE reads OS colors)

Comment: @LazyOne good suggestion. I tried that and the issue remains.

Comment: The problem has gone away. Perhaps reboot did something, or I didn't restart one service or another properly to test the config changes. @LazyOne changing colors to default is most likely what fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution appears to have been to restore the shell colors to default, and restart all the relevant services. Because I am unsure as to what was preventing the default colors to fix the problem, the solution may require an OS reboot.