# PhpStorm Darcula's console output bad contrast

Tags: phpstorm

I use PhpStorm with the Darcula theme.

I can't use the built in console because the output of error hasn't got enough contrast to be readable:

[image]

Did anyone managed to solve it? How?

Comment: Check comments and links in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41192988/windows-git-bash-intellij-git-bash-shell-color-scheme-messed-up-with-docker

Answer (score 0):

You have to go:

`File->Settings->Editor->Color Scheme->Console Colors->ANSI Colors->Red`

and then change color in `Foreground`.